# How to Crop image and set with aspect ratio with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site where two panels. one is left panel where menus(left panel size is 370px) and one is a right panel where content(mostly images) with padding-left 370px. in the right panel, I want to display full images in that section. right now I doing with jquery to set image height & width on doc ready. but it's got all images to stretch. so how to set all images with crop and with aspect ratio without stretch. here is my code.

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //retrieve current window height
    var finalWidth = windowWidth - 370;
    jQuery('.rightside > img').css({'height':windowHeight,'width':finalWidth});
    jQuery('.rightside').css('height',windowHeight);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="rightside"> 
    <img class="project_image" src="" />
    <img class="project_image" src="" />
    <img class="project_image" src="" />
    <img class="project_image" src="" />
    <img class="project_image" src="" />
</div>
```

Right now I am using 1920x1080 resolution and I am getting right-side panel current width & height 1533x924

Comment: Why do you mention PHP here? You're simply just scaling the images in the front end.

Comment: The images will of course be stretched: you are setting both the width **and** the height, so unless the images have the same aspect ratio as the right side panel, they will be stretched. The question is... how do you want to size the images? Do you want to set their width, or their height? If you want to set both and not stretch/compress the images, then you have to set them as background images on `<div>` and then use `background-size: cover`

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson sorry for that mate

Comment: @Terry tnanks mate but i have to use image tag. any chance to do with cropping. 
and all image is in a 1920*1080px resolution
so can i crop this images with 1533*924 resolution without stretched.

Comment: You can simply wrap the image with a `<div>` using jQuery, and then hide the `<img>` tag inside while setting the `<div>` background-image to the `src` attribute of the image tag.

Comment: What are your max desired width and max desired height for the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can solve this with pure css - no scripts needed. The main trick is to use a `div` with `background-image` style, and `background-size: cover`. This handles cropping and resizing (no matter the viewport size) and maintains aspect ratio.

Without seeing more of your code, I can't give a guaranteed solution. But if you've got your "right panel" filling the full viewport height, then the following would work:

```
<style>
    .image-container {
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="right-panel">
    <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url('/some/image.png');"></div>
</div>
```

Note that the `background-image` style is added to the html, not the style - that way you can reuse this class on many different images.

Comment: thanks but i have to use image tag. i can't use in background.

Comment: May I ask why? You'll end up having to do all the aspect-ratio math that `background-size: cover` does for you, and use quite a bit more styles.

Comment: i know i can use img as a background wiil help me. but i am doing for my client and he tells me to use img tag i don't know why?
they have to do something later with img tag that's why i have to use img tag.

Comment: I might have time later to provide an answer that does the aspect ratio math for you. But it's worth following up with your client to make sure this is necessary - it's not trivial, and it requires rendering the images briefly at their default sizes to get their "natural" heights and widths, which affects user experience.

Comment: thanks mate I really appreciate what you are doing. i explained client to do with by background but he is not want. i try argument on this but he is not understanding and not make any sense in a argument.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following steps and link :

1. https://github.com/josefrichter/resize/blob/master/public/preprocess.js
2. Create e Blob with the file data and get its url with [window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them)
3. Attach new hidden inputs to the original form and transfer the dataURI images basically as normal text
4. On backend, read the dataURI, decode from Base64, and save it